# NameError: name ... is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to make an RPG game in python 2.7 but, I run into this problem. I try to get pygame to draw starting_money and stam on the screen.(I have them in my **init** function in Player_1.py.) When I run it, it says starting_money and stam are not defined. (Yes, I have imported Player_1 via from Player_1 import *.) Here is an example of my code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from Player_1 import *
from monster import *

background_colour = (0,0,0)
(width, height) = (800, 800)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('RPG Game')
screen.fill(background_colour)

pygame.display(starting_money(500), stam(100))
pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      running = False`
```

and here is an example of Player_1.py

```
import pygame

pygame.image.load('player1.png')

class Hero:
    def __init__(self, hp, alive, starting_money, stamina, player1_sprite,     player1, run):

    self.starting_money = starting_money
    self.money = 500
    self.hp = 1
    self.hp = hp
    self.alive = True
    self.stam = stamina
    self.stamina = 100
    self.ps = player1_sprite
    self.run = run

    player1_sprite = 'player1.png'

def attacked(self, hp):
    if self.hp >= 1:
        self.alive = True
    elif self.hp < 1:
        self.alive = False

def stam(self, stamina):
    if self.stam > 0:
        self.run = True
    elif self.stam <= 0:
        self.run = False

def money(self, money):
    pass
```

I figured it out, thanks for responding guys.

Comment: How is `pygame` meant to know what this means? `pygame.display(starting_money(500), stam(100))`

Comment: `starting_money` is an attribute of a `Hero` object, `stam` is a method. Where is your `Hero` instance being created?

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html) doesn't seem to say you can call **`pygame.display`** as a function. What makes you think you can do this?

Comment: You seem to have a good deal of problems with this so it's hard to pick out what exactly is causing the issue. Even if we could get the code running, it's likely that you don't quite understand what's happening well enough to build on it. If you like, I have about an hour available and wouldn't mind helping out. If you have a github username, let me know what it is and I can invite you to a gitter session.

Comment: Thanks for the invite Adam. I'm sorry I didn't get back to you earlier. I have it figured out now. Thanks again. Peter, in my defense, I am still a beginner at python. THANKS AGAIN.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate your Hero from the Hero class that you wrote. So to create a hero with 500 starting money, 100 stamina and 100 hp, you would call:

```
galavant = Hero(100, 'placeholder', 500, 100, 'placeholder', 'placeholder', 'placeholder')
```

Then later calling:

`galavant.starting_money` and `galavant.stam` should yield 500 and 100, respectively.